# Turning Grayscale off on IE11 when loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have been trying to implement an accesibility function for a Website and one of my requirements is having a grayscale activated or deactivated on the click of 2 links. The users are still on Internet Explorer 11, so the compatibility with that navigator is a must.

So far, I have implemented some styles and code I found on the web and those are working great, I adapted the code, so I have 2 hyperlinks that execute a javascript function. One for enabling the grayscale and another one for disabling it.

But I have an issue, the grayscale is always turned on from the start whenever I load the page. I would like the grayscale starting disabled and then being enabled on by the click of one of my links.

Testing with Chrome and Firefox, the grayscales are turned off by default by adding the "grayscale-off" class to my images. Despite this, the issue persists on Internet Explorer.

So, I tried forcing the call to my javascript function that disables the grayscale on several parts:

Body

```
<body onload='enableEG(null)'>
```

Images themselves

```
<img src="img/FOV_8967.JPG" alt="Goal 1" width="600" height="400" class="grayscale grayscale-off" onload="enableEG(null)">
```

On the required script tag

```
<script src="js/jquery.gray.min.js" onload="enableEG(null)"></script>
```

Even tried creating a new script tag all the way to the bottom of my code, just before closing the body tag.

```
<script>enableEG(null);</script>
```

Interestingly, I put a couple of alerts that pop up when the function is executed, and they do appear when loading the page in IE with those forced function calls, however, the images still are grayscaled initially.

Here's my entire html code for reference (without the forced calls to the function):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Gray</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gray.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
      <script>

function enableEG(t){       
   var activeT = t; 
   //Internet Explorer
   var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
   if (isIE) {
      if ( activeT == null ){
         alert ("activateEG1: NULL; disable");
         $('.grayscale').toggleClass('grayscale-off',true);
      }
      else {
         alert ("activateEG1: 1; enable");
         $('.grayscale').toggleClass('grayscale-off',false);     
      }
   }
   //Other navigators
   else {
      if ( activeT == null ){
         document.documentElement.style.webkitFilter = 'grayscale(0%)';
      }
      else {
         document.documentElement.style.webkitFilter = 'grayscale(100%)';
      }        
   }
}

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Grayscale Test</p>   
      <p><a id="linkEnable" href="#" onclick="enableEG(1);">Enable</a></p>
      <p><a id="linkDisable" href="#" onclick="enableEG(null);">Disable</a></p>
      <div class="gallery">
         <a target="_blank" href="img/FOV_8967.JPG">
            <img src="img/FOV_8967.JPG" alt="Goal 1" width="600" height="400" class="grayscale grayscale-off"> 
         </a>
         <div class="desc">Goal 1</div>
         <a target="_blank" href="img/FOV_9088.JPG">
         <img src="img/FOV_9088.JPG" alt="Goal 2" width="600" height="400" class="grayscale grayscale-off">
         </a>
         <div class="desc">Goal 2</div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="js/jquery.gray.min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Update:

Found that I can turn off the grayscale if I put a script executing on a Window Load event after calling the external js, and it works like a charm on a single index page!

```
<script>
   $(window).on('load', function() {
      alert ("script function: turn off gray");                    
      enableEG(null);
   });
</script>
```

However, I'm still looking for a more permanent solution, because this fix doesn't work on internal pages that go beyond the index of the site I'm testing.

Comment: Why not create a class that turns the greyscale on instead of off? Might be easier to debug.

Comment: Ok, this line of code is loading the external JavaScript, and it also turns on the grayscale automatically <script src="js/jquery.gray.min.js"></script> I'll try to find a way to prevent it from executing on load  and insted execute it on the click of my links. Thanks, I'll get back to you later.